# Trigger windows Task Scheduler proccess few times a day between certain hours

Tags: windows, task

im trying to achieve something but i dont really know how
I have set a new basic task in windows task scheduler and on the advanced settings im trying to set something specific.

I want my job to **run between 7:00-23:59 every 3 hours**
In other words, i dont want the job to run at night..
(I tried using the expire checkbox but i am not doing things right)

edited: i use Windows Server 2008 standard

Any help would be great..

Comment: Hi which windows? In windows 7 you can add various triggers to a task which meets your requirements.

Comment: just added the windows information - i use Windows Server 2008 standard

Comment: Yes. Then it is the same thing I think. Neil's answer must be right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the advanced properties for the task. Select the Triggers tab. Edit the trigger. Change the schedule to start at 07:00 and repeat the task every 3 hours for 17 hours (you have to type those figures in yourself).